# How can I clear the cache for specific Flash games in Chrome?

Tags: macos, flash, google-chrome

My Sim Social game is broken in Chrome - it keeps loading but crashes after awhile *all the time*. I loaded it in Safari and it works. So I'm guessing Chrome somehow cached that failed swf file.

I just want to refresh it so that it is redownloaded again. I don't want to empty my complete cache as I also have Kongregate game saves(a lot of them tell you not to clear your cache at it will delete your saved games).

So the question is, where do I look for that specific cache folder in Chrome? I am using a Mac.

Comment: Migrated because the only gaming specific part here is the file that got corrupted belonged to a game :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cache can't contain saved games, so just go ahead and empty it. Some browsers have a "delete history"-like function though, which, along with the cache, may also remove elements that *can* contain them (such as cookies, HTML5 DOM storage, or Flash's "local shared objects").

What you could try:

- Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (Ctrl-F5 or Shift-F5 for Windows) on the offending page — this will cause Chrome to reload from the server, bypassing locally cached files.
- Use *Under the Hood → Clear Browsing Data*, but uncheck everything but "Empty the cache".

Comment: i've known command shift r but it doesn't really help me for this game at all. ive also tried clearing the cache to no avail. my "only" solution was to change to safari which was totally moot when it also happened to safari. now my only chance would be to use ff(since its now broken in chrome AND safari)

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse the browser cache with the flash cache.  Your flash cache is where saved games will be stored.  To view/modify it, go here:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

If you're suspecting a corrupt SWF file, you will want to clear your browser cache.  For chrome, press `ctrl`+`shift`+`del`.  Clearing your browser cache does not clear your flash cache.